# Numpy using smaller 2D array to map with bigger array with more elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have a smaller array as:

```
A = np.array([2011, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017])
Aval = np.array([14, 10, 35, 40, 45])
```

I have another array:

```
A2 = np.array([2013, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017])
```

I want to create A2val such that:

```
Arval = np.array([10, 35, 10, 35, 40, 40, 40, 45])
```

so, I am trying to use the values in array A to map to elements of A2 and generate an extended version of A2val

Please note 2011 is present in A, 2013 is in A2 but not in A2 and A respectively. I can use the following suggested in another thread:

```
Aval[np.searchsorted(A,A2)]
```

But it doesn't produce the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
>>> Aval[np.searchsorted(A, A2[np.nonzero(np.in1d(A2, A))[0]])]
array([10, 35, 10, 35, 40, 40, 40, 45])
```

Note that for getting the expected indices in default order the second array that you pass to `searchsorted()` should be contain the common items with first array.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a dictionary from `A` and `Aval` and then loop through `A2` and find out the corresponding values:

```
dic = dict(zip(A, Aval))
[dic.get(a) for a in A2 if dic.get(a) != None]
# [10, 35, 10, 35, 40, 40, 40, 45]
```