# Broadcast arrays in numpy based on search value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, search, indexing

I want to take aggregate values like:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
values = np.array([55, 66, 77])
```

and map that on a bigger "x-like" array

```
x_big = np.array([2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2])
```

so that I would get

```
# array([66, 77, 55, 55, 77, 66])
```

I've tried that using:

```
values_big = values[np.searchsorted(x, x_big, sorter=np.argsort(x))]
```

which somewhat works for a single-array case, but if I also need to map that over multiple arrays:

```
y1 = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2])
y2 = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
values = np.array([55, 66, 77, 88])
y1_big = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2])
y2_big = np.array([2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1])

# array([77, 66, 55, 88, 88. 55, 66])
```

I'm out of ideas.
How would you go about that?

Comment: What does *"x-like" array* mean?  What does "somewhat works" mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy using smaller 2D array to map with bigger array with more elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404793/numpy-using-smaller-2d-array-to-map-with-bigger-array-with-more-elements)

Comment: Well, that is basically what I already have for the single-array case. But my issue is with multi array extension.